# JS pageX and pageY take the coordinate plus the margin of relative position div?

Tags: javascript, css, events, position

I have a div that I want to center so I use

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
```

That's the easiest way to center I admit, but when I want to use event.pageX and event.pageY it takes the coordinates plus the left margin and that's wrong.

Here is the fiddle. Click somewhere on the green rectangle to watch the result :

http://jsfiddle.net/FGkUq/

Any ideas how to fix so to show the square to the coordinates without the left margin ?

Comment: That's the easiest way to center I admit, but when I want to use event.pageX and event.pageY it takes the coordinates plus the left margin and that's wrong. i cant understand this????

Comment: take a look at the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGkUq/1/).

Quick solution remove positioning of canvas:

```
#canvasDiv { 
    width: 30%;
    height: 400px;  
    cursor:crosshair;  
    background-color: #458B00; 
    /* position: relative; */  
    ...
}
```

The problem is with the positioning of template. Because `absolute` is still "relative".

The definition of absolute positioning: *An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.*

Therefore the position of `#template` will take into consideration the position of `#canvasDiv` unless you leave `#canvasDiv` with the default `static` positioning.

Learn more about positioning at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Positioning absolutely elements inside relatively positioned elements: [here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Great [example of your problem](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) tabs 3 & 4.

Should you wish to stick with the relative positioning of `canvasDiv`, you have to update the script, so it takes into account the positioning of `canvasDiv`:

```
var x = event.pageX;  
var y = event.pageY;   
var canvasPos = $(this).offset(); // in the context of your script this refers to #canvasDiv
var styles = {
   "left" : x - canvasPos.left, // remove its left offset
   "top" : y - canvasPos.top // remove its top offset
};
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGkUq/2/)

Comment: Yes, but in the example links the main (parent) div is with position : relative. Is it possible this way?

Comment: You can use the relative positioning of `canvas`, but then the script has to be aware of it also. (see updated answer)