# Javascript bootstrap open dropdown menu at mouse position

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want my bootstrap dropdown meny to be positioned at the mouse position. For some reason the pageX and pageY is wrong. In order to correct the position i have to add or subtract from x and y. BUT, if I then zoom in or out, the X and Y are incorrect again. I've tried everything out there. This is one of them..

**Html:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <div id="menuitems" onclick="setposition(event)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Menu
   </div>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="xxx" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menuitems">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"</i>Link 1</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#"</i>Link 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
function setposition(e) {
    var bodyOffsets = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    tempX = e.pageX - bodyOffsets.left;
    tempY = e.pageY;

    $("#xxx").css({ 'top': tempY, 'left': tempX });
}
```

What do I need to do in order to get correct X and Y position with different resolutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*It seems like on event wasn't called*

This works :

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/pEFhaLWTht

**JS**:

```
function setposition(e) {
    var bodyOffsets = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
    tempX = e.pageX - bodyOffsets.left;
    tempY = e.pageY;
  console.log(tempX);

    $("#xxx").css({ 'top': tempY, 'left': tempX });
}

$('#menuitems').on('click', function(e){
    setposition(e);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <div id="menuitems" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
   Menu
   </div>

   <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="xxx" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menuitems">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" <="" i="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" <="" i="">Link 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found another problem. My container has margin: auto which centers all the content. For some reason this interferes with the mouse position coordinates, (gives incorrect cords and different positions when zooming). Any way to bypass this or am i forced to not center my content (lol) ;D?

Comment: Alright I figured it out. I had a parent element that had margin:auto, which centered the complete website. I had to take that into consideration and add it to my X and Y.

Heres a good explanation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479179/js-pagex-and-pagey-take-the-coordinate-plus-the-margin-of-relative-position-div